# Upload file to Spring Boot Resource Folder, should not be that hard right

Tags: java, spring

I checked all over the internet and still cannot find the correct answer. I want to upload a file to the resources folder from Spring. So I can get the file from the heroku server when I deploy it.

For example applicationname/herokuapp.com/image.jpg

The structure of my app:

[image: Structure]

I tried and got a few problems :

1. File not found exception
2. Illegal char <:> at index 2
3. The file path I get is in the target folder??
4. Can't find path

I just need to get the correct path to the resources folder but I can't get it.

My controller with the following method looks like this:

```java
  @PostMapping(value = "/sheetmusic")
    public SheetMusic create(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("title") String title, @RequestParam("componist") String componist, @RequestParam("key") String key, @RequestParam("instrument") String instrument) throws IOException {
        URL s = ResourceUtils.getURL("classpath:static/");
        String path  = s.getPath();
        fileService.uploadFile(file,path);

        SheetMusic sheetMusic = new SheetMusic(title,componist,key,instrument,file.getOriginalFilename());
        return sheetMusicRepository.save(sheetMusic);
    }
```

The FileService:

```java
    public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String uploadDir) {

        try {
            Path copyLocation = Paths
                    .get(uploadDir + File.separator + StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename()));
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), copyLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I read something about jar but I don't understand it. I did not think it was this hard to just upload a file to a folder but I hope you guys can help me out!

EDIT : 
When I add this :
        String filePath = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:static").toString();

It will upload to the target folder which is not right.

EDIT 2 : IT IS FIXED

This is the right way to get the correct path :

```java
        String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/images/";
        fileService.uploadFile(file,path);
```

My folder structure is the following:
main
   -java
       - webapp
           - WEB-INF
               - images

Then I had to put this code into my MainApplicationClass

```java
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // Register resource handler for images
        // Register resource handler for images
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/images/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can change like overwrite any classpath resources. one more thing, after building a jar you cannot use `getUrl` to read any resources. I would suggest moving your resources to another folder. like for the first time the folder will automatically create. and then on you upload your files there. that will work.

Comment: to read a classpath resource, you must have to use: `var resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:my_image.png");
        var inputStream = resource.getInputStream();

        var bdata = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);
        var img = Image.getInstance(bdata);`

Comment: @Shoshi Yeah, The request is OK now, but Heroku tells me that it's a file only read system. java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Faded.pdf: Read-only file system. but there must be a way to upload right?

Comment: @Shoshi This is how my property looks like : https://imgur.com/a/TYOpoOG

Comment: I don't think you can change anything in the classpath. Cause all the resources are packed in the jar while it was built.

Comment: So what should I put in the classpath string? Keep it empty? I want it to reference it to the static folder :(

Comment: your main goal is to upload a new file to resources/static folder or replace the existing file there, right? In my opinion, it is not possible. you must have to use separate folder which is not built or packed with the jar.

Comment: if you are free, we can chat

Comment: @Shoshi Thanks for the option, if I can't get it to work I will contact u :)

Comment: @Shoshi I fixed it :D, I took the CanonicalPath which gives me the root path of my application and combined it with my folder structure :   
String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/images/";
This way worked for me! Even on the Heroku server :)

I also added a resource handler in my MainApplicationClass to handle the locations

Comment: You did able to change resources in jar? Wow that's great. You should post it as answer. It will help us also

Comment: @Shoshi Hey, I'm not sure if I was able to change the resources in jar ;p.Now I got the right path. I edited my post so you can check it out!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do here (replacing a file/uploading a file INTO a package .jar file) does not work, it is literally impossible.

You need to upload your file somewhere else, be that S3, some network drive etc, so that you application can reference it.

Comment: Why is it not possible? And what if I upload the image to the java folder instead of the resources folder? In NodeJS it does work but why can't it work in java :(?

Comment: You need to learn how to differentiate between what your project looks like in development (src/main/java /resources) folders, which is just a build tool (think: Maven/Gradle) convention. And what your project looks at runtime. At runtime it is just a .jar file (a .zip), which has no main/java/resources folder anymore. So you are basically asking: "Why can I not upload an image into a .jar file"...the answer is, because you cant :D

Comment: I fixed it :D, I took the CanonicalPath which gives me the root path of my application and combined it with my folder structure :   
String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + "/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/images/";
This way worked for me! Even on the Heroku server :)

I also added a resource handler in my MainApplicationClass to handle the locations